# How to pre-load modules into python scripts?

Tags: python, import

I would like to automatically import some Python modules that I regularly use into my scripts. E.g. instead of having to type every time

```
     import numpy as np
     import pandas as pd
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

have them automatically imported in every script.

Any tips on how to do this will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable to point to a script that has your imports written.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a go!